# How do I resolve to cast with smaller type?

Tags: c

Now I'm trying to implement with cast type in C.
But as you can see the image, there is some warning " cast to 'char*' from smaller integer type 'char'
I can't understand this, can't I implement like this type?
How can I resolve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"

typedef unsigned short     int uint16_t;
char * Rxcommand;


uint16_t DeQueue(void)
{
    retVal = 0x88;
    return retVal;
}


int main(void)
{
    
char ch;

ch = (char) DeQueue();
Rxcommand = ch;


../main.c(403): error:  a value of type "char" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char *"
```

So I used as the below instead.

```
Rxcommand = (char *) ch;
```

then I got a message as the below image.

[image]

Comment: `&ch` will give you a pointer to `ch`

Comment: Maybe you should use `char Rxcommand;` instead

Comment: Please explain **_why_** `Rxcommand` is a pointer to `char`.

Answer (score -2):

Before casting to pointer, make pointer!

```
Rxcommand = (char *) &ch;
```

Comment: Then you don't need the cast, of course.  "Needing" a cast often just means your code is broken, after all.